# Kendo validation message won't go away on ComboBox after selection is made

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I set a comboBox up like:

```
'<div class="k-edit-label" style="margin-top: -6px;"><label for="OwnerIdInput">Assigned To*</label>'+helpText+'</div>\n'+
                                        '\t<div data-container-for="OwnerIdInput" class="k-edit-field" id="ownerContainer" style="width: 300px; float: left; margin-left: 10px;">\n'+
                                        '\t\t<select type="text" id="OwnerIdInput" name="ownerId" required="required" data-bind="value:ownerId"></select>\n'+
                                        '\t</div>\n\n';
```

My issue is, that the combobox automatically fills with the current user. When the user removes themselves the validation pops up saying that something must be selected. When they make a selection, that validation rule stays there and never goes away.

I have validation popups for multiple fields (inputs, date time pickers...) where the message goes away when you correct the issue and they are set up the same. I am wondering if anyone may know why the combobox validation message won't go away, or how to make it go away when a selection is made.

I have though about using the 'change' event, but all these fields are dynamically added, so was hoping for something that may apply to all fields, and not have to have change events for every one.

Comment: This [kendo-ui validator](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/index) example seems to clear the validation message once something is selected... Can you reproduce the problem using Dojo?

Comment: Mmmk, the validator I just edited my question with seems to have done the trick. I didn't need any special buttons or anything. These fields were inside a kendo scheduler editor form, which did validation if the field was required, which I set it, but for some reason the multi select wouldn't detect something was chosen. But adding that validator made the validaton message go away :)

Comment: Please make answear for you question instead of update it.

Answer (score 0):

The following validator fixed this for me. No special buttons needed to be made or pressed (this is inside a kendo scheduler editor form, which handles validation checks on required inputs already). Just adding this made the validation message go away when something was selected.

```
 $('#validatorCheck').kendoValidator({
                                    rules: {
                                        hasItems: function(input){
                                            if(input.is('#OwnerIdInput')){
                                                var ms = input.data('kendoMultiSelect');
                                                if(ms.value().length === 0){
                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    },
                                    messages: {
                                        hasItems: 'Owner Must Be Selected'
                                    }
                                });
```